# PHP create new objects into array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, constructor

I've created a Magazine class with three properties in it which I wish to store directly into an array upon creating the objects. Now, what I thought I could do was just create new objects directly into the array, but it doesn't seem to work?

```php
<?php

class Magazine {

  public $id;
  public $name;
  public $price;

  public function __contruct($id, $name, $price) {
    $this->id =     $id;
    $this->name =   $name;
    $this->price =  $price;
  }

}

$magazines = array(
  new Magazine("svg_aftbld","Stavanger Aftenblad", 200),
  new Magazine("tsk_ubld","Teknisk Ukeblad", 300),
  new Magazine("se_ho","Se og H&oslash;r", 100),
  new Magazine("fam","Familien", 150)
);

print_r($magazines);

?>
```

Here's the output from the above code:

```
Array ( [0] => Magazine Object ( [id] => [name] => [price] => ) [1] => Magazine Object ( [id] => [name] => [price] => ) [2] => Magazine Object ( [id] => [name] => [price] => ) [3] => Magazine Object ( [id] => [name] => [price] => ) )
```

I also tried creating an empty array, and then filling it by pushing new objects in like so:

```php
<?php
array_push($magazines,new Magazine("svg_aftbld","Stavanger Aftenblad", 200));
array_push($magazines,new Magazine("tsk_ubld","Teknisk Ukeblad", 300));
array_push($magazines,new Magazine("se_ho","Se og H&oslash;r", 100));
array_push($magazines,new Magazine("fam","Familien", 150));
?>
```

But it resulted in the same output as before.

As you probably guessed, I'm learning PHP and I'm coming from Java. I've read several similar questions, but most of them seem to overcomplicate this. But I guess might be the one not quite understanding PHP. Feel free to lecture me in best practices too ;)

Comment: Typo related questions are off-topic. I can't see why an answer was given for this. Voted to delete.

Comment: Shouldn't I just delete myself then?

Comment: You probably won't be able after you've accepted an answer, but you can try. Otherwise, and since it was voted to delete, other members may also vote for it also. Use error checking http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php when developing. It will take the guesswork out of things. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you wrote `__contruct` instead of `__construct`...

Comment: I can't believe this. I've been trying so many different approaches to this and nothing would work. I'm also trying a new IDE that doesn't have proper syntax highlighting. This is so awkward.

Thank you so much! What should I do with my question? Should it be deleted?

Comment: as pointed out: `"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.`. This is a syntax mistake, not a programming issue

Comment: @cazyius simply, because it's only a typo and doesn't serve anyone. This won't help anyone in the future

Comment: I understand. Read the explanation after my comment. Deleted my comment when realizing my error. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.